# Search in :normal vim command misbehaves

Tags: search, vim

This popped-up while writing a script for vim.

Using the well-documented ':normal' command:

```
:normal /abc
```

does not search for the string *abc*. Instead, the previous search string is still active (i.e highlighted, jumped to with n, etc.).
Even stranger: the *abc* appears as the newest pattern in the / history (i.e. hitting / and then an up-arrow).

How come the *abc* does not take over as the true search pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help file for indeed well-documented `:normal` command says the following:

> If `{commands}` does not finish a command, the last one
>   will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `<C-C>` was typed.

When you write:,

```
:normal /abc
```

you try to execute unfinished command.  Indeed, after you type "`/abc`" in insert mode, you also should press "Enter" (i.e. `<CR>`).  This doesn't happen, but, according to manual, `<Esc>` is pressed.

To search via commands, you should use:.

```
:exec "/abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Finishing the Command

[P Shved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388594/474798) is correct, if the command is not finished it will be aborted. But you can finish the command. you need to to provide the Enter key stroke, just like when perform a search manually. But just hitting the `Enter` key won't work as it will execute the normal command, not add it to the command you're executing *with* normal.

Use `Ctrl-V Enter` to add a literal Enter to your command (displayed as `^M`. See `:h i_CTRL-V`). You can't use `<Enter>` or `<CR>` like you would with a mapping.

```
:normal /abc^M
```

This will perform the search and, if you add more to your normal command after the search, perform the remainder of the command starting at the match for the search.

### Unexpected Results

Doing this may not get the desired results as the search will find examples outside the current line. For example, consider you've selected the first 3 lines of the text below in visual mode.

```
example text  " <--- Visual Selection
sample text   " <---
more words    " <---
text test
```

Executing the following command will delete the word `text` on lines 1, 2, and 4 even though 4 isn't selected in visual mode.

`:'<,'>norm /text^Mdw`

To only affect the lines in the range you need to limit the search to the current line use the following (see `:h \%l`):

`:'<,'>norm /\%.ltext^Mdw`

This limits the search the the cursor line and will only delete `text` on the first 2 lines in the example above.